# error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/wdtrue'

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have created a C++ project in Visual Studio 2013, With Opencv 3.0 Configured.
Iam getting this error **"error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/wdtrue'"** while building the project in debug mode.
I have seen similar posts regarding this, but, Could'nt find the solution to solve this error.

With reference to this post,
[Remove secure warnings (_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS) from projects by default in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883037/remove-secure-warnings-crt-secure-no-warnings-from-projects-by-default-in-vis)
Included "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" in project configuration. But still the error continues.

Also, Made the following configuration to project
Configuration Properties-> C/C++-> All Options-> WarningLevel :Turn Off All Warnings (/W0)

This change also did'nt helped me to solve error.

Please Provide Any Solution to this error.

Comment: What command line does the project properties say is used for the C++ compiler?

Comment: @Berriel I agree. But I mean here, VS has shown these, like errors in the Project. Googling solution to this error, shown me how to suppress these errors.(warnings ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler switch `/wdtrue` appears to be invalid. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx):

> /wdn
>
> Disables the compiler warning that is specified in n.
>
> For example, /wd4326 disables compiler warning C4326.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I produced this error by making a mistake in VS project settings:
I entered in Configuration Properties/ C/C++ / Disable Specific Warnings : C4996
 this leads to:  "error cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/wdC4996"

Solution: Change the setting from C4996 to 4996.