# Fread_s to save specific word?

Tags: c, file, fread

I have to complete this exercise:
I have to read from a generic text file, thus composed:
[Nameperson][space][age],and i have to save the name(char) and the age(unsigned int) in a struct.

My problem is:
I don't understand how to divide the name and age, that is, if I use a fread_s, in this way

> fread_s(pp->name, 256, 1, 256, f);

the program saves me as name es.

> Pippo 25iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii...

I know that the fread_s function maintain the position of the last letter read, but I do not know how to use this to my advantage
.
This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
    char name[256];
    unsigned int age;
};

void person_read(FILE *f, struct person* pp) {
    fread_s(pp->name, 256, 1, 256, f);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong function, you need `fscanf()`

```
int
person_read(FILE *file, struct person *person)
{
    // Warning: if names contain spaces "%255s%d" will not work
    if (fscanf(file, "%255s%d", person->name, person->age) != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: invalid read!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Use it like this

```
struct person person;
if (person_read(file, &person) != 0)
    do_somethin_read_error();
else
    fprintf(stderr, "%s has %d years\n", person.name, person.age);
```

The reason your code is producing that output is because you are reading all the bytes from the file (*or just 256*) into `person->name` and since `person->name` is not *null* terminated, passing it to `printf()` produces the output you see and is *Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: About fscanf Visual Studio said 'This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fscanf_s instead.' how can i solve it?

Comment: And that's why I don't like Visual Studio for students because it tries to force non standard functions. I knew it would say that, but I don't write code for MS Operating system so I can't help you with that sorry. I think if you add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in the very beginning of your file [it should silence the warnings and you would be able to use **standard** functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883037/remove-secure-warnings-crt-secure-no-warnings-from-projects-by-default-in-vis).

Comment: You solve it as you "*Consider using `fscanf_s` instead.*" (instead of `fscanf`)