# Multiple errors, in header files in VS2017, opengl project C++

Tags: c++, header, visual-studio-2017

So Im working on **opengl** project from learnopengl and I am a beginner in C++ so I have little problem with it. It is a VS2017 project.

I have problem with `main.cpp`, when I compile it it shows this error:

> name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace
>
> - it is in (FileSystem::getPath) so when i include filesystem.h in main.cpp it shows another error but in filesystem.h : cannot open
>     source file "root_directory.h"

so I downloaded `root_directory.h` from https://github.com/alifradityar/LastOrder same for `entry.h`. Now I have 10 warnings and 3 errors :-) just this is what happens when one wants to repair one error.

`logl_root` undeclared identifier from `filesystem.h` 23 next 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. Every help is welcome.

I know I am only beginner but how am I supposed to learn it without trying to deal with problems ? And I know how stupid this question is :D...

Here if full project in 7z.:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vNTkh9HEcMKvM8Yzm0iCTJtx1d2xqvlR

filesystem.h, root_directory.h and entry.h are in /includes/learnopengl
lib-s and includes are linked in VS.

> line: 24 - logl_root undefined 23 - 'getenv': This function or
>   variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable
>   deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. Every help is welcome.

```
**filesystem.h**



#ifndef FILESYSTEM_H
#define FILESYSTEM_H

#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "root_directory.h" // This is a configuration file generated by CMake.

class FileSystem
{
private:
  typedef std::string (*Builder) (const std::string& path);

public:
  static std::string getPath(const std::string& path)
  {
    static std::string(*pathBuilder)(std::string const &) = getPathBuilder();
    return (*pathBuilder)(path);
  }

private:
  static std::string const & getRoot()
  {
    static char const * envRoot = getenv("LOGL_ROOT_PATH");
    static char const * givenRoot = (envRoot != nullptr ? envRoot : logl_root);
    static std::string root = (givenRoot != nullptr ? givenRoot : "");
    return root;
  }

  //static std::string(*foo (std::string const &)) getPathBuilder()
  static Builder getPathBuilder()
  {
    if (getRoot() != "")
      return &FileSystem::getPathRelativeRoot;
    else
      return &FileSystem::getPathRelativeBinary;
  }

  static std::string getPathRelativeRoot(const std::string& path)
  {
    return getRoot() + std::string("/") + path;
  }

  static std::string getPathRelativeBinary(const std::string& path)
  {
    return "../../../" + path;
  }


};

// FILESYSTEM_H
#endif


**root_directory.h**



#ifndef __ROOT
#define __ROOT
#include "entry.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class RootDirectory {
public:
    vector <Entry> data;
    RootDirectory();

    string toString();
    void load(string);
};
#endif#ifndef __ROOT
#define __ROOT
#include "entry.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class RootDirectory {
public:
    vector <Entry> data;
    RootDirectory();

    string toString();
    void load(string);
};
#endif


**main.cpp**



#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stb_image.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <learnopengl/shader_m.h>
#include <learnopengl/camera.h>
#include <learnopengl/filesystem.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
unsigned int loadTexture(const char *path);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2.0f;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0f;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // tell GLFW to capture our mouse
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    Shader lightingShader("5.4.light_casters.vs", "5.4.light_casters.fs");
    Shader lampShader("5.4.lamp.vs", "5.4.lamp.fs");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        // positions          // normals           // texture coords
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,

        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f
    };
    // positions all containers
    glm::vec3 cubePositions[] = {
        glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
        glm::vec3(2.0f,  5.0f, -15.0f),
        glm::vec3(-1.5f, -2.2f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(-3.8f, -2.0f, -12.3f),
        glm::vec3(2.4f, -0.4f, -3.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.7f,  3.0f, -7.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.3f, -2.0f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.5f,  2.0f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.5f,  0.2f, -1.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.3f,  1.0f, -1.5f)
    };
    // first, configure the cube's VAO (and VBO)
    unsigned int VBO, cubeVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    // second, configure the light's VAO (VBO stays the same; the vertices are the same for the light object which is also a 3D cube)
    unsigned int lightVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &lightVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(lightVAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    // note that we update the lamp's position attribute's stride to reflect the updated buffer data
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // load textures (we now use a utility function to keep the code more organized)
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    unsigned int diffuseMap = loadTexture(FileSystem::getPath("resources/textures/container2.png").c_str());
    unsigned int specularMap = loadTexture(FileSystem::getPath("resources/textures/container2_specular.png").c_str());

    // shader configuration
    // --------------------
    lightingShader.use();
    lightingShader.setInt("material.diffuse", 0);
    lightingShader.setInt("material.specular", 1);


    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // be sure to activate shader when setting uniforms/drawing objects
        lightingShader.use();
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.position", camera.Position);
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.direction", camera.Front);
        lightingShader.setFloat("light.cutOff", glm::cos(glm::radians(12.5f)));
        lightingShader.setFloat("light.outerCutOff", glm::cos(glm::radians(17.5f)));
        lightingShader.setVec3("viewPos", camera.Position);

        // light properties
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.ambient", 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        // we configure the diffuse intensity slightly higher; the right lighting conditions differ with each lighting method and environment.
        // each environment and lighting type requires some tweaking to get the best out of your environment.
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.diffuse", 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
        lightingShader.setVec3("light.specular", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        lightingShader.setFloat("light.constant", 1.0f);
        lightingShader.setFloat("light.linear", 0.09f);
        lightingShader.setFloat("light.quadratic", 0.032f);

        // material properties
        lightingShader.setFloat("material.shininess", 32.0f);

        // view/projection transformations
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        lightingShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        lightingShader.setMat4("view", view);

        // world transformation
        glm::mat4 model;
        lightingShader.setMat4("model", model);

        // bind diffuse map
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, diffuseMap);
        // bind specular map
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, specularMap);

        // render containers
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // calculate the model matrix for each object and pass it to shader before drawing
            glm::mat4 model;
            model = glm::translate(model, cubePositions[i]);
            float angle = 20.0f * i;
            model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f));
            lightingShader.setMat4("model", model);

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        }

        // again, a lamp object is weird when we only have a spot light, don't render the light object
        // lampShader.use();
        // lampShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        // lampShader.setMat4("view", view);
        // model = glm::mat4();
        // model = glm::translate(model, lightPos);
        // model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f)); // a smaller cube
        // lampShader.setMat4("model", model);

        // glBindVertexArray(lightVAO);
        // glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);


        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &lightVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
// -------------------------------------------------------
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse scroll wheel scrolls, this callback is called
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}

// utility function for loading a 2D texture from file
// ---------------------------------------------------
unsigned int loadTexture(char const * path)
{
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        stbi_image_free(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        stbi_image_free(data);
    }

    return textureID;
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly how to fix the problem.  Which part of it do you not understand?

Comment: To me it looks like `#include "root_directory.h" // This is a configuration file generated by CMake.` hints at running CMake to create a project, not to try to download some files with a matching name.

Comment: And for `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, this is the first hit on Google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883037/remove-secure-warnings-crt-secure-no-warnings-from-projects-by-default-in-vis

Comment: The CMake run should've created the configuration directory and included it. Do you have that file? Downloading it was the worst idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make this an answer instead of a comment (although I probably should be a comment). As you told yourself you want to learn. So instead of telling you a "solution", I'll try to show you the ropes how to properly deal with this kind of problems.

First and foremost, the most important part when dealing with compilation errors is to actually *read* the error message and then to **understand** it! *Don't jump to conclusions, download arbitrary files from unrelated sources and mash things together!* This approach won't work!

Let's break this down. You have a compiler error. It reads like the following:

> > ```
> > (…) name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace (…)
> > ```

Your quote, unfortunately is missing some information, namely in what file at which line the problem occoured. There's a certain logic behind how compilers report errors; older versions of GCC spat out rather arcane error logs, often several pages long; the culprit usually hides somewhere in the very first 5 lines or so of the whole error log. Usually you can safely ignore all the rest.

Anyway, it tells you what is wrong. Namely, that in C++ if you write something like `a::b` then `a` must be the *name of a class or a namespace* (which is exactly what the error tells you). However usually classes and namespaces are pulled in by a header include. If a include directive fails the preprocessor does bail out though, so it's unlikely that this has anything to do with a missing include at all.

But what can happen as well is, that *before* an include something is not how it should be. Usually a missing semicolon (`;`). which might cause a class declaration to be mangled up with something else.

So here's what you should do: Carefully reread the compiler log *from the beginning*. Look at all the warnings and errors on top, then work your way down.

If you get stuck again, **edit** your question, and *if* I can help you, I'll append to this answer.

Comment: Thank you for response, now I realized that I shoult aproach that problem other way, same for cmake which I was using only for implementing libs and includes.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still searching for an answer...

// The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.