# Scanning space as char

Tags: c, char, scanf

So I have a simple code that scans every letter of a word and writes it's value and adress using a pointer.

My problem is that  %c doesn't scan spaces, and I would like them to. How do I manage that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c1, c2, *p_c;
    while (scanf_s(" %c", &c1) == 1)
    {
        if (c1 == '*')
            break;
        p_c = &c1;
        c2 = *p_c;
        printf("c1: %c (%p) c2: %c (%p) c_p: %c (%p)\n", c1, &c1, c2, &c2, *p_c, p_c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example

Input:

```
is this C?*
```

Expected output:

```
c1: i (00D3F7CF) c2: i (00D3F7C3) c_p: i (00D3F7CF)
c1: s (00D3F7CF) c2: s (00D3F7C3) c_p: s (00D3F7CF) 
c1:   (00D3F7CF) c2:   (00D3F7C3) c_p:   (00D3F7CF)
c1: t (00D3F7CF) c2: t (00D3F7C3) c_p: t (00D3F7CF)
c1: h (00D3F7CF) c2: h (00D3F7C3) c_p: h (00D3F7CF)
c1: i (00D3F7CF) c2: i (00D3F7C3) c_p: i (00D3F7CF)
c1: s (00D3F7CF) c2: s (00D3F7C3) c_p: s (00D3F7CF)
c1:   (00D3F7CF) c2:   (00D3F7C3) c_p:   (00D3F7CF)
c1: C (00D3F7CF) c2: C (00D3F7C3) c_p: C (00D3F7CF)
c1: ? (00D3F7CF) c2: ? (00D3F7C3) c_p: ? (00D3F7CF)
```

My code just entirely skips spaces as if they weren't there at all.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output you show, is that the *actual* or the *expected* output? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also, with the `scanf` format `" %c"`, what do you think that leading space does? Please read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information.

Comment: Specifically the paragraph immediately following the heading **"A directive is one of the following:"** in [scanf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: the format specifier '%c' can pickup ANY byte value, including a space.  The core of the problem is that the format string to `scanf()` is " %c" and the leading space results in ALL leading 'white space' to be skipped.  (white space is spaces, tabs, newlines, etc )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Coding error**

`"%c"` with `scanf_s()` requires 2 arguments, `rsize_t` and `char*`.
This also implies compilation might not be done with all warnings enabled.
Save time, enable all warnings.

> The `scanf_s` function is equivalent to `fscanf_s` with the argument `stdin`
>   interposed before the arguments to `scanf_s`. C11dr §K.3.5.3.4 4
>
> The `fscanf_s` function is equivalent to `fscanf` except that the `c`, `s`, and `[` conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments ...   §K.3.5.3.2 4

```
// scanf_s(" %c", &c1)
scanf_s(" %c", &c1, sizeof c1)
```

---

> My problem is that %c doesn't scan spaces, and I would like them to. How do I manage that?

**`" "` consumes white-space**

To *not* consume white-space like `' '`, omit the leading `" "`

```
// scanf_s(" %c", &c1, sizeof c1)
scanf_s("%c", &c1, sizeof c1)
```

Or simplify with `scanf()`

```
scanf("%c", &c1)
```

Or simplify further with `getchar()`

```
char c1;
int ich;
while ((ich = getchar()) != EOF) {
  c1 = (char) ich;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the space helped, I was using it in earlier stages to get rid of problems with print.

Although I can't use the scanf function, because my compiler in Visual Community Studio 2017 never let's me not use the scanf_s, says it may be unsafe...

Comment: @MichalKováč Perhasp [Remove secure warnings ... from projects by default in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16883037/2410359).  IAC, `scanf_s()` is not safer than `scanf()`.