# How can I get the size of the array in an 3D matrix?

Tags: c

Consider the following 3D matrix

```
char ShapesArray[2] = { 
  (char[4][4]){
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //I
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 }
  }, 
  (char[3][3]){
    { 0, 1, 0 },    //J
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 0 }
  }
};
```

by using

```
int i = sizeof(ShapesArray[0]));
```

I would expect 16 as result.
But the result in this case is: `1`

What am I missing here?

Comment: `char ShapesArray[2]` is defining a 1D array of two `char` elements.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so this is not actually a 3D array?

Comment: Your compiler should throw some warnings about excess initializers

Comment: I wish it would, but it has no warnings at all.

Comment: MSVC generates **two** warnings of *'initializing': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from ...* and **one** error *COFF format cannot statically initialize '_ShapesArray' with 1 byte(s) of an address.* But the array `char ShapesArray[2]` is supposed to have two `char` elements so `sizeof(ShapesArray[0])` (one closing parenthesis) is `1` so that part is correct.

Comment: I think the static `sizeof` cannot be used here. I would define a `struct` with `size_t size_x, size_y;`

Comment: @WeatherVane Should i change my compiler? If i am not mistaken, arduino uses GCC behind the scenes

Comment: Try compiler option `-Wall`

Comment: First, lookup if there's a way to turn errors up? eg, `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @NeilEdelman I think i got your point. By using something like ShapesArraySize {
    int *Array;
    size_t size;
  };

Comment: To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`.

Comment: MSVC "/Wall Displays all warnings displayed by /W4 and all other warnings that /W4 does not include," if you want to really turn it up a notch, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883037/remove-secure-warnings-crt-secure-no-warnings-from-projects-by-default-in-vis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char ShapesArray[2]` is an array of two `char`s. Hence the first element's size is 1. Turn on the [compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/IZDXh1):

```
<source>: In function 'main':

<source>:4:2: error: initialization of 'char' from 'char (*)[4]' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]

    4 |  (char[4][4]) {

      |  ^

<source>:4:2: note: (near initialization for 'ShapesArray[0]')

<source>:10:2: error: initialization of 'char' from 'char (*)[3]' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]

   10 |  (char[3][3]) {

      |  ^

<source>:10:2: note: (near initialization for 'ShapesArray[1]')

cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Compiler returned: 1
```

What the compiler is saying is that you're initializing `char`s with `char (*)[4]` and `char (*)[3]` which is wrong. It wouldn't even compile with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Actually it does with arduino. Sketch uses 1972 bytes (6%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.... Will try that though. Thank you all